# /Library/Application Support now off limits?

Tags: macos

The [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1) say:

> /Library (Mac OS X only)—Applications that share resources between users store those resources in this version of the Library directory. Sandboxed application are not permitted to use this directory.

Our app isn't sandboxed, but when I try to create a "/Library/Application Support/NewFolder" folder in there I get the following message:

> You don't have permission to save the file "NewFolder" in the folder "Applcation Support."

I can't find anywhere else suitable to use for sharing files that need to be read and written by different users - /Users/Shared doesn't seem right, and apparently we can't access /Library without authorization.

Where can I store files that should be user-independent, but also writable by our application? 
 It would suck if I ended up having to duplicate files multiple times if different users used an app on the same machine.

Comment: What about /Users/Shared/Library/Application Support doesn't seem right? Is there a security issue?

Comment: Is that really appropriate for applications to put stuff in? It sounds like a folder for users to muck about with, not applications. Looks like there isn't even a /Users/Shared/Library folder to put stuff in, so I'd have to put it in /Users/Shared/NewFolder directly.

Comment: Since /Library/Application Support is not user-/other-writable, you need to escalate privileges in other to create your own directory there. Have you done that?

Comment: I have not - I don't want to escalate privileges at all, I just want somewhere that my application can access shared files in.

Comment: @Colen As far as I can tell, you’ll need to escalate privileges in order to create a directory under /Library/Application Support. This could be done during installation, and you could set your directory to be other-writable. After that, the application itself wouldn’t need to escalate privileges to use that directory.